# How to upload image with Angular and PHP

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new in Angular, I am trying to upload image from angular but getting 4 errors:

1)in post method: Cannot find name 'formData'. Did you mean 'FormData'?ts(2552) 
2)In subscribe method: const headers: HttpHeaders 
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 5,
3) In subscribe method:Cannot find name 'file'. Did you mean 'File'?ts(2552)
4) In this.url: Type 'string | ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to type 
'string'.
  Type 'ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to type 'string'

Below i am attaching code.

```
public imagePath;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  url: string;
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  onSelectFile(event) 
  { // called each time file input changes
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) 
    {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        this.imagePath = event.target.files;

        for (const file of this.imagePath) 
        {
          const formData = new FormData();
          formData.append('image', file, file.name);
        }
        const headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
        headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');

        this.http.post('http://localhost/imageupload.php', formData).subscribe( headers, console.log(file.name) );

        reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]); // read file as data url

        reader.onload = (event) => { // called once readAsDataURL is completed
        this.url = event.target.result;

      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constants are block-scoped, you do not have the access constant from the outer scope (for is a block-scoped)

```
public imagePath;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  url: string;
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  onSelectFile(event) 
  { // called each time file input changes
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) 
    {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        this.imagePath = event.target.files;

        for (const file of this.imagePath) 
        {
          const formData = new FormData();
          formData.append('image', file, file.name);

          const headers = new HttpHeaders();
          headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
          headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');

          this.http.post('http://localhost/imageupload.php', formData, { headers }).subscribe(response => console.log(response));

          reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]); // read file as data url

          reader.onload = (event) => { // called once readAsDataURL is completed
          this.url = event.target.result;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: But still error in subscribe method in headers, and on this.url